# Where should I put "approximately"?

Tags: adverbs

Which of these three sentences is correct and why:

> A) The prices **approximately** increased by 20%
>
> B) The prices increased **approximately** by 20%
>
> C) The prices increased by **approximately** 20%

Answer (score 1):

Put *approximately* with the term it modifies:

- *approximately increased* has *approximately* modifying *increased* ... what could that mean? Did prices not actually 'increase' but just do something close to 'increase'? But prices either increase or decrease or stay level, so *approximately increased* doesn't seem very likely.
- *approximately by 20%* has *approximately* modifying *by 20%* ... what could that mean? Did prices not actually increase *by* 20% but do something involving a different preposition, such as *behind* or *across from*? But *by* is the preposition we use to measure percentage changes, so that doesn't seem very likely.
- *approximately 20%* ... what could that mean? Did prices not actually increase by exactly 20% but by a different number close to 20%, such as 19.73% or 20.4%, or by a range of different numbers for different products, all in the neighbourhood of 20%? That's a common way of rounding numbers to give a readily intuited sense of scale, so that in fact seems very likely.

*C)The prices increased by approximately 20%* is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using http://www.dictionary.com,

> **approximately**
>
> /əˈprɒksɪmɪtlɪ/
>
> adverb
>
> 1.
>   close to; around; roughly or in the region of

The correct sentence to use would be

> C)The prices increased by approximately 20%

This sentence conveys the idea that there has been an increase in the price and that increase is around 20 %